# JQuery start and end dates should execute different functions for different start and end dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

My problem is I want to execute different functions on different dates. All my function execution depends on the dates which we select. For example, if I select last 7 days in my code it should execute a different function and if I select last one month it should execute another function. But when I click on apply I am able to execute only one function. I have tried lots of chunks of code but I could not find the answer. please help me out

```
 $(function() {
var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
var end = moment();


function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    minDate: moment().subtract(365, 'days'),
    maxDate:moment(),
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    },
},

    cb)
cb(start, end);
});
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function() {
 addtoday();
 addyesterday();
 presentmonth1();
 last30days();
 anydate();


  });
  </script>
```

If I want to write an if else for the moment() how should it be done. When I click on different date ranges I have to execute or trigger different functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using daterangepicker, the parameters of `apply.daterangepicker` event's second parameter has information regarding the chosen option based on which, you can call you desired function. See below:

```
$(function () {
    var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
    var end = moment();


    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        minDate: moment().subtract(365, 'days'),
        maxDate: moment(),
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
        },
    },

        cb)
    cb(start, end);
});
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {

    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Today") {
        addtoday();
    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Yesterday") {
        addyesterday();
    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 7 Days") {
    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 30 Days") {
        last30days();
    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "This Month") {
        presentmonth1();
    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last Month") {

    }
    else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Custom Range") {

    }

});
```

Comment: Perfect, Perfect,Perfect